# How to configure duplicate screen on a Pi?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, hdmi, display, touchscreen

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 connected with a TouchScreen.
I also connect another external display via HDMI.

[image]

## Goal

I've been trying to make my external display show as `duplicate` mirror the one on the touch screen, instead of showing the command line.

I don't know what is the option to do that.

Can someone please provide some hints ?

Comment: Not posting this as an answer as I don't know whether this works on the Pi and I don't have mine set up to check, but have a look at `xrandr` - perhaps that will get you started.

Comment: Is `xrandr` is a command or an app ? Shall I run it as a command ?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?  (It's a command.)